# Potential across the capacitor in LC Circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, capacitance

Below is the circuit as an example.

> **Situation**: Initially the Switch $S_1$ is closed for a long time and circuit comes to steady state. Now, consider t=$0$ and the switch $S_2$ is closed as well as $S_1$ is opened.

[image]

I know that when the Switch $S_2$ is closed the inductor has maximum energy and Capacitor has zero energy. This becomes a case of LC Oscillation. If we were to find the maximum potential developed in the capacitor then
$$\frac{1}{2}.L.{i_o}^2 = \frac{1}{2}.C.{V_{max}}^2$$
where $i_o = \frac{100~V}{50~Ω} = 2~A$

so, $$V_{max} = 100√5~V$$

Now, the problem begins. **If the initial EMF source provided only $100~V$ then how is the maximum potential of the capacitor $100√5~V$ ? Also, what happens to the current in meanwhile ?**

Doubt in the following concepts --

1. Do we get more potential than the applied to conserve energy when energy is transferred from inductor to the capacitor?

> My Solutions to the problem --
>
> 1. Maybe the method to find the maximum potential in not correct.
> 2. That is how it has to be to conserve energy, probably.

I am not sure what is correct and what not.

Comment: Why do you think the voltage has to be the same?

Comment: Initially this thought came because I saw applied voltage is less than what I had got for capacitor and that was counter-intuitive. Maybe to Conserve Energy it happened this way, is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the initial EMF source provided only 100 V then how is the maximum potential of the capacitor 100√5 V ?

You wrote down the correct equation relating the initial current in the inductor to the maximum voltage developed across the capacitor.

As you can see, the EMF of the source that originally charged the inductor does not appear in this equation, and therefore it has no bearing on the maximum voltage to be developed across the capacitor.

For an intuitive explanation, consider that when the LC tank is oscillating, the voltage source is no longer connected to the circuit, and therefore its properties can't affect the behavior of the circuit.

A similar principle is used in engineering in the design of [boost converters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter) that convert a low voltage power supply to a higher voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The current has a lot of inertia due to the inductor, so it continues through the new path. This current charges up the capacitor (with energy).

The inductor is able to charge the capacitor to almost the same energy as the inductor had initially (there are some losses due to resistance in the coils and circuit wires). So with small enough capacitance, it seems arbitrarily high voltage on the capacitor can be achieved.

In practice this is limited by the fact the inductor has some ohmic and radiation resistance to current, and part of energy will be lost to heat and radiation.

Still, in practice with a strong enough inductor, it is relatively easy to achieve multiplication of small voltage in range of volts to voltage in range of hundreds/thousands of volts.

Inductor just as the electrochemical cell can be source of energy, but it works differently. Inductor, as opposed to electrochemical cell, has no natural limit on voltage it can help to create - the voltage reached is the higher the quicker is the inductor discharged. The voltage achieved in practice will depends on the rest of the circuit.